# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor a través de un atributo XSL?

Tags: xml, xsl, xslt

**Tengo el siguiente documento XML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <document>
       <comarca nom="Alt Camp">
          <centres>
             <numero tipus="public">6</numero>
             <numero tipus="privat">2</numero>
          </centres>
          <professors>
             <numero tipus="public">223</numero>
             <numero tipus="privat">34</numero>
          </professors>
       </comarca>
</document>
```

**Y tengo que obtener lo siguiente mediante XSL**
Documento: Transform.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
   <comarca>
      <nom>Alt Camp</nom>
      <centres>2</centres>
      <professors>34</professors>
   </comarca>
  </document>
```

**De momento he conseguido obtener el nombre de la etiqueta comarca, lo que no consigo obtener es el contenido de la etiqueta numero con el atributo @privat:**

```
<xsl:template match="/document">
    <document>
            <xsl:for-each select="comarca">

                <comarca>
                    <nom>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@*" />
                    </nom>

                    <centres>

                        <xsl:value-of select="centres/numero/@privat" />
                    </centres>

                    <professors>
                        <xsl:value-of select="professors/numero/@privat" />
                    </professors>
     </document>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hola. Edita, por favor, el XSL que no parece correcto.

Comment: Lo acabo de editar, tuve que recortar códio en la publicación de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de filtrar por el atributo `tipus` en el tag `numero` es la siguiente `[@tipus='privat']` entonces el `XSLT` quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/document">
      <document>
         <xsl:for-each select="comarca">
            <comarca>
               <nom>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@*" />
               </nom>
               <centres>
                  <xsl:value-of select="centres/numero[@tipus='privat']"/>
               </centres>
               <professors>
                  <xsl:value-of select="professors/numero[@tipus='privat']"/>
               </professors>
            </comarca>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </document>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Salida:

```
<document>
   <comarca>
      <nom>Alt Camp</nom>
      <centres>2</centres>
      <professors>34</professors>
   </comarca>
</document>
```